# Can Access ensure a new form record displays all fields?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a database where I don't want some fields showing depending on data in other fields.  I'm still new to VBA, having learnt how to do things I need via the internet (there's not much call for it in my job so like to try it out on side projects) for the things I need and have managed to create some code that hides certain fields that aren't needed, depending on what's been entered in another field and that works okay, if not perfectly (I'd like it to only work on the current record and not all of them at once but will worry about that later).  My problem is, if I'm entering information onto a record and any of those fields become invisible exactly as I would want them to, then if I have more records to complete and load a new record, those hidden fields are also hidden on the blank record before any data has been entered and I want each new record to show all fields from the outset.

Another thing I've noticed is that if I close the database, next time I go into it the hidden fields have unhidden themselves again so I know I'm missing something important.

Here's a screenshot of a bit of the code where I want 2 other fields (What_reason and Date_sent_to_new_owning_School) to be visible depending on whether the answer in the current field after update is "Standard" or "Non-standard":

[image: link to my bit of code]

I'm sorry if this is really entry-level stuff but I AM entry level and trying to learn.  This bit does work, albeit not perfectly as I'd like it to only work on the record I'm in at the time, and not go through and hide that field in all the other records at once (which it's doing).

I've searched everywhere but can't find the answer and although I've tried, I'm nowhere near good enough at VBA to try and use common sense to work it out.  Is this something that can be done?  I'm okay with computers generally and with Access too but I'm aware there's an awful lot I don't know and this is why I'm trying to do new things and learn stuff that I've not used before. I have tried all day to get this to work but am admitting defeat and am hoping somebody here will be able to help me.  I'll probably need 'idiot level' advice if that's possible, I know my limitations. :)

Comment: Back in my learning days I often had a solution to a problem in my head and I wanted to know how to code that solution.  Often that "solution" wasn't really the solution.  You'd be better off sharing what the problem you are trying to solve by hiding fields under certain conditions is.   There is probably a better solution.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes that's probably very true with me too.  All I want is for a new record to show all fields where the record before has had some of them hidden, if that makes sense.

My database also isn't remembering that they were hidden when I've closed it and gone back into it either so there's something important missing somewhere.

Comment: I would edit your post then.  Share the code you are using to hide fields and potentially a screenshot of your form.  Then tell use explicitly where you are getting stuck.

Comment: Dynamically hiding controls on form set in Continuous or Datasheet is not really practical because property setting affects ALL instances of control. Db is not going to 'remember' dynamic setting - code needs to be executed when form opens - so it is needed in OnCurrent event as well as control's AfterUpdate. Code should be provided as text, not image. Conditional Formatting can dynamically enable/disable textbox/combobox by record although control is still visible.

Comment: Also, code is easier to read with proper indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know how to use the Event tab in the Property Sheet? You can set all of your fields to [field].Visible = True on either: On Current, On Load, or On Open
[Screenshot of the Property Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYvD3.png) and for the field that determines the visibility of all of the other fields; you can use the Event: After Update so that way when you click/tab away from that field, it'll make those changes for you!

Answer (score 0):

Property setting affects **ALL** instances of control. Control will be visible/not visible for all records depending on conditions of current record. Therefore, dynamically hiding controls on form set in Continuous or Datasheet will **NOT** give the desired result of

> only work on the current record and not all of them at once

Db is not going to 'remember' dynamic setting - code needs to be executed when form opens and/or navigating records - so it is needed in OnCurrent event as well as control's AfterUpdate.

**Conditional Formatting** can dynamically enable/disable textbox/combobox by record although control is still visible.